# Connect to a specific port of container from inside a container

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, containers

I have a node js application running in a docker container which is running on port 3000, on the same container I have installed nginx server. on this container I am trying to receive connection on port 80 i.e. nginx port and then it passed the connection to node js server i.e. running on port 3000 in same container.

Is it possible to achieve this ? if yes then how ?

Comment: A typical setup would be to run an Nginx reverse proxy and a backend service on two separate containers, and then you could use the setup in for example [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) to `proxy_pass http://nodejs-application:3000` in the Nginx configuration.  Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

you can setup nginx as a reverse proxy with the port on which your app is running

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }
}
```

add this to your `/etc/nginx.conf` inside the container.